# SDL2 main game loop

Tags: c++, rendering, sdl, sdl-2

My question popped out while reading the tutorials on SDL2, on lazyfoo.net and the code is being copied from  [this page](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/07_texture_loading_and_rendering/index.php)

```
int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{

//Start up SDL and create window

if( !init() )
{
    printf( "Failed to initialize!\n" );
}
else
{
    //Load media
    if( !loadMedia() )
    {
        printf( "Failed to load media!\n" );
    }
    else
    {
        //Main loop flag
        bool quit = false;

        //Event handler
        SDL_Event e;

        //While application is running
        while( !quit )
        {
            //Handle events on queue
            while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) != 0 )
            {
                //User requests quit
                if( e.type == SDL_QUIT )
                {
                    quit = true;
                }
            }

            //Clear screen
            SDL_RenderClear( gRenderer );

            //Render texture to screen
            SDL_RenderCopy( gRenderer, gTexture, NULL, NULL );

            //Update screen
            SDL_RenderPresent( gRenderer );
        }
    }
}

//Free resources and close SDL
close();

return 0;
}
```

Here why are we rendering the effects inside the main loop and make it run again and again rather than like:

```
int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
//Start up SDL and create window
if( !init() )
{
    printf( "Failed to initialize!\n" );
}
else
{
    //Load media
    if( !loadMedia() )
    {
        printf( "Failed to load media!\n" );
    }
    else
    {
        //Main loop flag
        bool quit = false;

        //Event handler
        SDL_Event e;

       //Clear screen
       SDL_RenderClear( gRenderer );

        //Render texture to screen
        SDL_RenderCopy( gRenderer, gTexture, NULL, NULL );

        //Update screen
        SDL_RenderPresent( gRenderer );

        //While application is running
        while( !quit )
        {
            //Handle events on queue
            while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) != 0 )
            {
                //User requests quit
                if( e.type == SDL_QUIT )
                {
                    quit = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//Free resources and close SDL
close();

return 0;
}
```

I suppose there is a reason as this is done in many tutorials.
But i am unable to get the reason.

Comment: Just wanted to mention the `SDL_QUIT` event is generated by clicking the `X` icon on the upper right of the SDL window, not by pressing the Escape key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You render the screen again and again because typically things represented on the screen are changing.  To represent those changes you need to update the display.  For example, if a ball is moving across the screen and you only render the screen once, the ball will not appear to move.  However, if you continue to "run again and again" then you will be able to see the ball move across the screen.

Comment: I accept ur ans... but let me know onething. ... y should i render it again n again if i know its not changing.... like in my example its a static texture

Comment: The point of this tutorial is to show you how you can render a texture in that kind of application, you could now apply translations or rotations and observe the changes. The point of this tutorials is not to simply render a texture and be done with it, its a simplification of a more complex program. You can do it that way for the particular example, render once, but usually a graphical application will keep drawing itself. If you really love drawing only once, you can make it so the application only renders IF there was a change, which is up to you how to implement.

Comment: @Sagar Kar There are two types of rendering, Passive and Active.  Passive rending only renders the screen when it needs to.  This approach is typically used in windowed GUI applications with controls and no dynamically animated things going on.  In passive rendering, the screen still needs to update itself, just not on a clock-like basis.  Active rendering is used in things like video games to constantly update the screen.  [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/rendering.html) is a good article describing the differences between active and passive rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Lazyfoo's tutorials are pretty good, I'd say stick to them.

For some reason the lessons on update time and frame rates are 24 and 25, which I'd say is a bit late but they're there.

Like I said in the comment, it's [Event Driven Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming). The main loop should read events, such as key presses and mouse clicks, update your application using how much time has passed since the last update and then render it. This will happen X times per second, which is the frame rate.

That code is made in a way in which it could later acommodate this time checking but the lesson on that comes later.

This is an example for a very simple main loop.

```
while ( appIsRunning ) {
    handleEvents();

    update( deltaTime );

    render();

    // If frames were 30, wait 33 ms before running the loop again
    delay( 1000/frames ); 
}
```

Comment: Main drawback here is that you are not taking into account the time spent in handleEvents()/update()/render() making the loop not really scalable. Good approach would be to rely on the current time.