# How to display a texture in SDL2?

Tags: c, sdl

I have a problem with SDL2, I'm trying to render a fully red surface with SDL2 but it doesn't work, the window closes immediately, it seems like the program exits in SDL_RenderPresent() function, I think the wrong part is my fillSurface function but I don't see what I did wrong (I'm trying to fill a SDL_Surface in red pixel by pixel then display it on screen), thanks for the help.

Here's my code:

```
#include <header.h>

int     fillSurface(SDL_Surface *surface, unsigned char r, unsigned char g, unsigned char b, unsigned char a)
{
    uint32_t    color;
    uint32_t    *pixels;
    int         i;

    if (SDL_BYTEORDER == SDL_BIG_ENDIAN)
        color = a + (((uint32_t)b) << 8) + (((uint32_t)g) << 16) + (((uint32_t)r) << 24);
    else
        color = r + (((uint32_t)g) << 8) + (((uint32_t)b) << 16) + (((uint32_t)a) << 24);
    if (SDL_LockSurface(surface))
        return (-1);
    pixels = (uint32_t*)surface->pixels;
    i = 0;
    while (i < surface->w * surface->h)
        pixels[i++] = color;
    SDL_UnlockSurface(surface);
    return (0);
}

int     exitFailure(t_sdlVar *sdl)
{
    if (sdl->renderer)
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(sdl->renderer);
    if (sdl->screenSurface)
        SDL_FreeSurface(sdl->screenSurface);
    if (sdl->screenTexture)
        SDL_DestroyTexture(sdl->screenTexture);
    if (sdl->window)
        SDL_DestroyWindow(sdl->window);
    sdl->renderer = NULL;
    sdl->screenSurface = NULL;
    sdl->screenTexture = NULL;
    sdl->window = NULL;
    SDL_Quit();
    return (-1);
}

int     main(void)
{
    t_sdlVar    sdl;

    sdl.renderer = NULL;
    sdl.screenSurface = NULL;
    sdl.screenTexture = NULL;
    sdl.window = NULL;
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)
    || !(sdl.screenSurface = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, 800, 600, 32, RMASK, GMASK, BMASK, AMASK))
    || SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(800, 600, 0, &sdl.window, &sdl.renderer)
    || fillSurface(sdl.screenSurface, 255, 0, 0, 255)
    || !(sdl.screenTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(sdl.renderer, sdl.screenSurface))
    || SDL_RenderCopy(sdl.renderer, sdl.screenTexture, NULL, NULL))
        return (exitFailure(&sdl));
    SDL_RenderPresent(sdl.renderer);
    SDL_Delay(1000);
    return (0);
}
```

Header:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
# define HEADER_H

# include <math.h>
# include <unistd.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <SDL.h>
# include <SDL_image.h>

# if SDL_BYTEORDER == SDL_BIG_ENDIAN
#  define RMASK 0xff000000
#  define GMASK 0x00ff0000
#  define BMASK 0x0000ff00
#  define AMASK 0x000000ff
# else
#  define RMASK 0x000000ff
#  define GMASK 0x0000ff00
#  define BMASK 0x00ff0000
#  define AMASK 0xff000000
# endif

typedef struct      s_sdlVar
{
    SDL_Surface     *screenSurface;
    SDL_Texture     *screenTexture;
    SDL_Renderer    *renderer;
    SDL_Window      *window;
}                   t_sdlVar;

#endif
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/30738868/1216776

Comment: So is this because I have to do the while (isquit = SDL_FALSE) loop in order to make the window render? Because it didn't work with a while (1) either